# Sharing VS 2010 One-Click Web Publishing Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, one-click-web-publishing

Anybody know where the VS 2010 One-Click Web Publishing settings are stored?

It would be awesome it a team could share the settings so a quick deployment to a test system is always a button click away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's stored in the same project directory as the project you've deployed, stored as an XML file.  Look for a *.Publish.xml